# Cannot ping server 1 from pc 1 in packet tracer file by setting default route on all 3 routers connected with serial DTE cables

Tags: networking, router, ping

I am working on an assignment and I am stuck. I connected have 3 routers, 3 switches, 4 computers, and a server. I have created 2 vlans which router 2 and switch 2 use. I can ping between the computers and the internet but not server 3 which is connected to router 3.  I am trying to ping server 1 from PC1 but receive a "timed out" response every time. The connections are as follows: router s0/1/0 is connected to router 2 s0/1/1, router 2 s0/1/0 is connected to router 3 s0/1/0, and router 3 is connected to router 1 s01/1. All of the serial connections are using a 255.244.244.252 subnet which allows for 2 hosts. I tried to set up a default route according to the instructions. For instance, router 1's s0/1/0 points to router 2 s0/1/1 at 0000.0000.0000.0000 0000.0000.0000.0000 172.16.68.2 and I thought I had done so correctly for the other two routers but I just received the "timed out" error when pinging the server from any of the computers I have to have the equipment set up the way it is I cannot alter it in any way per the instructions. Could someone please take a look at the packet tracer file that I have uploaded to GitHub? Here is the link:  https://github.com/MissChaos1991/PacketTracer
Also, I have uploaded an image of the snippet of the instructions specifying how you are supposed to get packets to travel between all three routers.

I have tried to follow the IP address pattern specified in the instructions and it still failed to ping the server. I received a "timed out" error. If I deviate from the pattern I end up receiving a "destination host unreachable" when trying to ping the server from PC1 (or any of the PCs).